# Test Average and Grade - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python program which when you enter 5 test scores it displays the corresponding letter grade and then gets the average of those five grade and displays the letter grade for the average.

Here's my program:

```
#Test Average and Grade

#Enter 5 test scores
test1 = int(input('Enter score 1: '))
test2 = int(input('Enter score 2: '))
test3 = int(input('Enter score 3: '))
test4 = int(input('Enter score 4: '))
test5 = int(input('Enter score 5: '))

total =(test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5)

#Calculate average
def calc_average(total):
    return total / 5

#Grading scale
def determine_score(grade):
    if 90 <= grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'


grade = total
avg = calc_average(total)
abc_grade = determine_score(grade)

print("That's a(n): " + str(abc_grade))
print('Average grade is: ' + str(avg))
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the grade to display after each score that is entered and I am having trouble trying to figure out how to get the letter grade to display along with the average in the last statement.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Changed program to this:

```
 #Test Average and Grade

#Enter 5 test scores
test1 = int(input('Enter score 1: '))
test2 = int(input('Enter score 2: '))
test3 = int(input('Enter score 3: '))
test4 = int(input('Enter score 4: '))
test5 = int(input('Enter score 5: '))

total =(test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5)

    #Calculate average
    def calc_average(total):
        return total / 5

    #Grading scale
    def determine_score(grade):
        if 90 <= grade <= 100:
            return 'A'
        elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
            return 'B'
        elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
            return 'C'
        elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
            return 'D'
        else:
            return 'F'

    grade = total
    avg = calc_average(total)
    abc_grade = determine_score(grade)

    print("Score 1:", determine_score(test1)) 
    print("Score 2:", determine_score(test2)) 
    print("Score 3:", determine_score(test3)) 
    print("Score 4:", determine_score(test4)) 
    print("Score 5:", determine_score(test5)) 
    print("The average grade is: %s which is a(n): %s " % (str(avg), abc_grade))
```

Results look this this:

Enter score 1: 75
Enter score 2: 80
Enter score 3: 33
Enter score 4: 90
Enter score 5: 52
Score 1: C
Score 2: B
Score 3: F
Score 4: A
Score 5: F
The average grade is: 66.0 which is a(n): F

Trying to get the results like this:
Enter score 1: 75
That's a(n): C
Enter score 2: 80
That's a(n): B
Enter score 3: 33
That's a(n): C
Enter score 4: 90
That's a(n): A
Enter score 5: 52
That's a(n): F
The average grade is: 66.0 which is a(n): F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have it print the letter grade as a user enters a score you can do something like:

```
#Calculate average
def calc_average(total):
    return total / 5

#Grading scale
def determine_score(grade):
    if 90 <= grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'

#Enter 5 test scores
scores = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    score = int(input('Enter score {0}: '.format(i)))
    print 'That\'s a(n): ' + determine_score(score)
    scores.append(score)

total = sum(scores)
avg = calc_average(total)
abc_grade = determine_score(avg)


print('Average grade is: ' + str(avg))
print("That's a(n): " + str(abc_grade))
```

The letter grade problem was that you were using total which was all the grades added up (hopefully more than 100 if you got at least a 20 on all 5 assignments), so it would always default to the else. You want to use the `avg` so that it would give you the letter grade corresponding to the average:

```
abc_grade = determine_score(avg)
```

You can also omit the `grade = total` line because you will never use grade after making this change.

Comment: After i enter a score I'm trying to get a letter grade to correspond with each score I enter.  Enter Score 1: 75
    That's a(n) C.  Then when it figures the average of the 5 scores I'm trying to get the letter grade to display with the average of the 5 scores.  Basically the last thing that prints for the average would be : Average grade is:_ Which is a (n) _.  Hopefully that explains it a little better.

Comment: @Aaron check my answer

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Aaron no problem, dont forget to accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

As said previously, if you want to get the correct grade letter you need to change your code from:

```
abc_grade = determine_score(grade)
```

to:

```
abc_grade = determine_score(avg)
```

I'm not 100% sure what you meant in your last question where you asked how to display the grade letter after the average grade but if i understood you correctly you can just do this:

```
print "The average grade is: %s and the grade letter of the average is: %s " % (str(avg), abc_grade)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def main():
    score1 = 0.0
    score2 = 0.0
    score3 = 0.0
    score4 = 0.0
    score5 = 0.0
    avg = 0.0

    score1 = getScore1()
    score2 = getScore2()
    score3 = getScore3()
    score4 = getScore4()
    score5 = getScore5()

    findAvg = calc_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
    letterGrade = determine_grade(findAvg)

    print('Score\t\t Numeric Grade   Letter Grade')
    print('------------------------------------------------')
    print('Score 1:\t', score1, '\t\t', determine_grade(score1))
    print('Score 2:\t', score2, '\t\t', determine_grade(score2))
    print('Score 3:\t', score3, '\t\t', determine_grade(score3))
    print('Score 4:\t', score4, '\t\t', determine_grade(score4))
    print('Score 5:\t', score5, '\t\t', determine_grade(score5))

    print('Your final average is: ', findAvg, ',', 'This is your letter   grade: ', letterGrade)

def getScore1():
    score1 = float(input('Enter score 1: '))
    return score1
def getScore2():
    score2 = float(input('Enter score 2: '))
    return score2
def getScore3():
    score3 = float(input('Enter score 3: '))
    return score3
def getScore4():
    score4 = float(input('Enter score 4: '))
    return score4
def getScore5():
    score5 = float(input('Enter score 5: '))
    return score5

def calc_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5):
    total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5
    avg = total / 5
    return avg

def determine_grade(findAvg):
    if findAvg >= 90 and findAvg <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
        return grade
    elif findAvg >= 80 and findAvg <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
        return grade
    elif findAvg >= 70 and findAvg <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
        return grade
    elif findAvg >= 60 and findAvg <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
        return grade
    else:
        grade = 'F'
        return grade
main()
```

Comment: Please take your time and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) how to write a good answer.